# compress floating point numbers with specified range and precision

Tags: java, compression, floating-point

In my application I'm going to use floating point values to store geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude).

I know that the integer part of these values will be in range `[-90, 90]` and `[-180, 180]` respectively. Also I have requirement to enforce some fixed precision on these values (for now it is `0.00001` but can be changed later).

After studying single precision floating point type (`float`) I can see that it is just a little bit small to contain my values. That's because `180 * 10^5` is greater than `2^24` (size of the significand of float) but less than `2^25`.

So I have to use double. But the problem is that I'm going to store huge amounts of this values, so I don't want to waste bytes, storing unnecessary precision.

So how can I perform some sort of compression when converting my double value (with fixed integer part range and specified precision X) to byte array in java? So for example if I use precision from my example (`0.00001`) I end up with 5 bytes for each value.
I'm looking for a lightweight algorithm or solution so that it doesn't imply huge calculations.

Comment: After you compact your data you can still use compression, e.g. GZIPOutputStream which may make it smaller again.

Comment: @PeterLawrey for array with decent size should be very useful. I think your suggestion have something common with suggestion of Aaron - they both exploit the fact that stored values will be close to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store a number `x` to a fixed precision of (for instance) `0.00001`, just store the integer closest to `100000 * x`. (By the way, this requires 26 bits, not 25, because you need to store negative numbers too.)

Comment: thanks! But there are some questions when using this approach. So you suggest storing `int store = round(value / precision)`. Let's take example: `value1 = 1.34, value2 = 1.36`, precision is `0.1`. Then we have `|value1-value2| = 0.02 < precision`, so these values considered equal. But we store these values as `round(1.34/0.1)=round(13.4)=13` and `round(1.36/0.1)=14`. So when we restore them they become 1.3 and 1.4, considered not equal. This example is not exact as many values can't be represented in computer (famous 0.1), it just show possible problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: @pavel, whatever method you use, there will be numbers arbitrarily close to each other that get stored as different compressed numbers. Otherwise all numbers would have to be stored the same! Think about  it...

Comment: got it, for some time lost the meaning of "precision". Indeed close values can be stored as different but their difference will never be greater than difference of original values by more than 'precision' threshold. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As [TonyK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428857/tonyk) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382678/34088), use an `int` to store the numbers.

To compress the numbers further, use locality: Geo coordinates are often "clumped" (say the outline of a city block). Use a fixed reference point (full 2x26 bits resolution) and then store offsets to the last coordinate as `byte`s (gives you +/-0.00127). Alternatively, use `short` which gives you more than half the value range.

Just be sure to hide the compression/decompression in a class which only offers `double` as outside API, so you can adjust the precision and the compression algorithm at any time.

Comment: a very valuable notice, Aaron! Thanks! I have to spent some time though to think about implementing the idea without violating OOP principles.

Comment: Create the most simple implementation that fits your needs and optimize later (when you know what is slow). Just make sure that the API is simple and doesn't expose any internals. I suggest a simple list-like approach: `size()` returns number of coordinates and then `get(int index)` to get a point. Keep some values in an internal cache because most accesses will be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your use case, i would nonetheless use **double** and compress them directly.

The reason is that strong compressors, such as [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), are extremely good at handling "structured" data, which an array of double is (one data = 8 bytes, this is very regular & predictable).

Any other optimisation you may come up "by hand" is likely to be inferior or offer negligible advantage, while simultaneously costing you time and risks.

Note that you can still apply the "trick" of converting the double into int before compression, but i'm really unsure if it would bring you tangible benefit, while on the other hand it would seriously reduce your ability to cope with unforeseen ranges of figures in the future.

[*Edit*] Depending on source data, if "lower than precision level" bits are "noisy", it can be usefull for compression ratio to remove the noisy bits, either by rounding the value or even directly applying a mask on lowest bits (i guess this last method will not please purists, but at least you can directly select your precision level this way, while keeping available the full range of possible values).

So, to summarize, i'd suggest [direct LZMA compression](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) on your array of double.

Comment: You have it completely backwards. If the numbers have any noise in the low-order bits, then these bits (which are not needed anyway) will be incompressible.

Comment: It all depends on the source. As stated by pavel : "enforce some fixed precision on these values (for now it is 0.00001 but can be changed later)". So either the source data comes with this precision, or the selection precision can be enforced, using a simple double->double function. More importantly, the precision can changed later, without modifying the methodology.

Comment: This is such a terrible idea, it hurts my teeth to think about it.

Comment: What about the performance costs? If I compress/decompress array of 1000 geo points using integer approach and 7zip, will the difference be noticeable?

Comment: Performance difference between compressing directly double and compressing an integer representation of it (fixed point arithmetic) is likely to be small, both speed wise and compression wise.
The real issue is about complexity. By creating an intermediate format, There is one more reason to worry about, not just today, but also for tomorrow's code maintenance. So it has to provide some real benefits to be worthwhile.

Comment: @TonyK what particular detail in his suggestion do you consider being a bad idea? While I find your notice about low order bits really useful, he provided solution to it.

Comment: @pavel: No he didn't. He just ignored it. If you store those low-order bits, you will probably be storing them unconmpressed. That's just wasted space -- precisely what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Maybe a test will tell more and be more meaningfull. It's not the first time someone tries to hand-tune input data to further compress it, just to be disappointed by lower-than-expected results (for example, check this entry by Con Kolivas : http://ck-hack.blogspot.com/2010/10/on-lrzip-and-packing-bytes.html) . 
It just happens than 7z is very good at structured data. It cannot be told the same from other algorithms, such as zip or ppm.
A major exception is when source data is drastically changed using a delta model for example, but that's a completely different story.